# How to pass arguments to linux command prompt using python script

Tags: python, linux, shell, devops, system-administration

Demo.py

```
import os
f = os.popen('passwd')
```

---

output:

Enter Existing Password: (This one i want program to enter )

I am running this python program which prompts me to Enter existing password. But i want to send that existing password through the program.

is there any way i could pass that value to command prompt via program.

Comment: You'll have to echo the password to the commandline from your program

Comment: I don't think `passwd` reads its input from standard input, it always reads from the terminal.

Comment: Do you need a specific solution for "passwd"? passwd expect 3 inputs (existing passwd, new passwd, new passwd). would you like to provide all 3 inputs from the python program, or only the 1st parameter from python program and the 2 others should be entered by the user?

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve this by using python's expect module. I have written the sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pexpect
import sys
child = pexpect.spawn('passwd')
child.logfile=sys.stdout
child.expect("UNIX password:")
child.sendline('guest')
child.expect('Enter new UNIX password:')
child.sendline('guest')
child.expect('Retype new UNIX password:')
child.sendline('guest')
```

You can also check more details of expect module at http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/how-to-use-the-pexpect-module-in-python